# Bash: Delete a line from a file matching a variable

Tags: bash, quoting

I have four files named source, correct, wrong and not_found. I am trying to write a script in bash wherein I read each line from file named source, store the line as variable x, and match it against a condition.

If it passes, then I need to write that line to file named correct, but the catch is before writing into correct I need to check if the variable x is currently present in file named wrong and if yes delete it and then add the line to file named correct.

I have tried below, but it doesn't modify the file and neither gives me any output:

```
sed -i '/$x/d' ./wrong
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `sed`, not `send`. If you use single quotes, there will be no expansion, so you're actually searching for `$x` (literally), not the contents of that variable. Use double quotes instead: `sed -i "/$x/d" ./wrong`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. It was actually my iPad doing the auto correct. I have corrected the error now.

Comment: `sed` does not modify the file: reads from standard input and writes on the standard output. You need to put the result somewhere  and then substitute the original file. something like: `sed -i '/$x/d' ./wrong > ./wrong.new && mv ./wrong ./wrong.old && mv ./wrong.new ./wrong` (if you want to keep a copy of the old one).

Comment: Thanks Costi Ciudatu, it works as expected after adding the double quotes. I am new to bash and probably wasted couple of hours over this small mistake. sed -i "/$xd" ./wrong works now. The single quotes were preventing the variable x from being expanded and the script was matching x and not the value inside it. Adding double quotes now matches the value of x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already understood, variables inside `'...'` are not expanded.

If you replace the single-quotes with double-quotes,
this will delete the matching line from `./wrong`:

```
sed -i "/$x/d" ./wrong
```

But you also want to add the line to `./correct`, if there was a match.
To do that, you can run `grep` before the `sed`:

```
grep "$x" ./wrong >> ./correct
```

This will have the desired effect,
but `sed` will overwrite `./wrong`, even when it doesn't need to.
You can prevent that like this:

```
if grep "$x" ./wrong >> ./correct; then
    sed -i "/$x/d" ./wrong
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Janos, I actually to need to delete line containing x and the next two lines following it from ./wrong. Also,

Comment: Thanks Janos, I actually to need to delete line containing x and the next two lines following it from ./wrong. So, I am doing if grep "$x" ./wrong;then;sed -i "/$x/,+2d" ./wrong;echo $x>>./correct;echo line2>>./correct:fi I am running a separate for loop before this if loop to keep hold of line2 and line3. The decision of whether I want to delete x from wrong depends on line2 and line3. Hence, I can't directly copy line containing x and next two lines directly from wrong to correct.

Comment: @DattarayaHonrao you are adding important new details that were not part of the original question. It would be better to ask a new question, including all the details that you really need.